# how to get tagged message on page using graph api

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I need to get message which tagged on myself page with graph API.

First I create one page named `myfirstapppage`, then, using another user (not the page owner), posted a message that tagged the `myfirstapppage` page.

I found the message in my created page, but cannot get this message by graph API.

I had the access_token, and can using it to retrieve the posts data on this page.

Any one meet this problem?